# How to find the limsup of function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to find the following limit $$\limsup\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\int\limits^x_0 t\ln(1+t) dt}{x^2} ?$$

Answer (score 2):

$\limsup\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\int\limits^x_0 t\ln(1+t) dt}{x^2} ?
$

You are only interested in
small $t$,
so use the first terms
of the power series
$\ln(1+t)
=t+O(t^2)
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
\int\limits^x_0 t\ln(1+t) dt
&=\int\limits^x_0 t(t+O(t^2)) dt\\
&=\int\limits^x_0 (t^2+O(t^3))dt\\
&=\dfrac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\dfrac{\int\limits^x_0 t\ln(1+t) dt}{x^2} 
=\dfrac{\dfrac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4)}{x^2} 
=\dfrac{x}{3}+O(x^2) 
$
so the limit is $0$.

Note that
if the denominator was
$x^3$,
the limit would have been
$\dfrac13$.

Comment: Do you know if L'Hopitals rule is a valid approach when examining $\lim \sup$? It gives the same result in this particular example.

Comment: @Mattos Since the limit exists, it is the same thing.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks.

Comment: @marty cohen More complicated solution.

Comment: Mine often are.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\int\limits^x_0 t\ln(1+t) dt}{x^2} =\lim_{x \to0}\frac{x\ln(1+x)}{2x}=0.$$
So limit exists and $$\limsup\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\int\limits^x_0 t\ln(1+t) dt}{x^2} =\liminf\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\int\limits^x_0 t\ln(1+t) dt}{x^2} =\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\int\limits^x_0 t\ln(1+t) dt}{x^2}=0$$